# Fast Report Dot Matrix fixed Length

Tags: fastreport

I have created a dot matrix report via Fast Report, which I want to export to .txt, but with fixed length width. To be more specific below is the export that i want to achieve.

[image]

I have placed the data so that I have the desired result, I have added specific width, I have disabled the auto width and i have set the margins to 0 (for page settings). I use font Courier 10. I have to somehow define in the program that does the export(Delphi) that I want fixed length?